# Custom FormField with different state type and onsaved type

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm trying to create a custom formfield which represents full name.
It includes 2 TextInputs firstname and lastname.
Now, I want the value returned in onSaved to be "firstname lastname" (which means it should extend FormField), but I want to store the first name and the last name sepeately (which means it should extend FormField>).
I don't really want the tuple but how else can I store the fields seperately?

Is it possible to store the firstname and the last name as 2 different values in the state, and maybe define a getter which will return the full name?

Comment: Please show some code what you have tried so far?

Comment: I don't know where to start... maybe I'll create an ordinary widget instead..